# Translate a sample from Haskell to Scala (HKT, type constraints)

Tags: scala, haskell, type-constraints, higher-kinded-types

I'm learning Functional Programming, I made this sample in Haskell it works like I want, but when I don't know how to do such constraint in Scala, I don't understand how I can use HKT and Constraints in Scala atm.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Complex
  ( Complex
  , add
  ) where

data Complex a where
  Complex :: (Show a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> Complex a

instance Show (Complex a) where
  show (Complex a b) = "z = " ++ show a ++ " + i * " ++ show b

add :: Complex a -> Complex a -> Complex a
add (Complex a b) (Complex c d) = Complex (a + c) (b + d)
```

Thanks in advance :)

So, I did it but it seems kinda wrong, can I make It better ?

```
  case class ComplexNumber[T](realPart: T, imagPart: T){
    override def toString: String = s"z= $realPart + $imagPart i"
  }

  object ComplexNumber {
    def add[T](a: ComplexNumber[T], b: ComplexNumber[T])(implicit evidence: Numeric[T]): ComplexNumber[T] = {
      ComplexNumber(evidence.plus(a.realPart, b.realPart), evidence.plus(a.imagPart, b.imagPart))
    }
  }
```

It seems strange I have to use this evidence helper..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "evidence helper" guarantees that type parameter `T` is limited to numeric types that can be added together (or any other arithmetic operation).

It can be hidden behind some syntactic sugar making `T` a "context bound" type parameter. You can also bring in some extra implicits to make the addition syntax more natural.

```
object ComplexNumber {
  import Numeric.Implicits._  //can be placed elsewhere in the file
  def add[T: Numeric](a: ComplexNumber[T], b: ComplexNumber[T]):ComplexNumber[T] =
    ComplexNumber(a.realPart + b.realPart, a.imagPart + b.imagPart)
}
```

You can also go for a more natural client-side syntax.

```
import Numeric.Implicits._
case class ComplexNumber[T: Numeric](realPart: T, imagPart: T){
  override def toString: String = s"z= $realPart + $imagPart i"
  def +(that: ComplexNumber[T]):ComplexNumber[T] =
    ComplexNumber(this.realPart + that.realPart, this.imagPart + that.imagPart)
}
```

Usage:

```
ComplexNumber(8,1) + ComplexNumber(4,4)  //res0: ComplexNumber[Int] = z= 12 + 5 i
```

Answer (score 0):

hopes this help, but can't make object generics sorry

```
case class Complex[T](real: T, img: T) {
    override def toString: String = s"z= $real + $img i"
}

object Complex {
    def add(cmplx: Complex[Double], cmplx2: Complex[Double]): Complex[Double]
        = new Complex[Double](cmplx.real + cmplx2.real, cmplx.img + cmplx2.img)
}

val c1 = Complex[Double](3, 4)
val c2 = Complex[Double](5, 1)

println(Complex.add(c1, c2))
```